# Set dimensions of component by percentage

Tags: c#, winforms

I need to set the width and length of my components(e.g. DGV(`DataGridView`)) after re-sizing the form (e.g. maximizing) by percentage. For example the width of my DGV should become 100% and the height of it should become 45%.

I read about Dock and Anchor but I could not implement my idea by these options.

Is there a appropriate method for this problem?

Comment: For those of us who don't know what DGV is...?

Comment: @oddparity I would guess `DataGridView`

Comment: yes it is 'DataGridView'(DGV).

Comment: You can try to calculate the new Width and Height using simple calculation in the Form resized event,and then assign those values to your DataGridView component.Calculate new Width=45% of Previous client area,and new Height=Height of your Form's client area.

Comment: Thanks @Avril but various monitors have different resolutions and this calculation is good just for my resolution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a [`TableLayoutPanel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) handle your layouting.

For your example, create a `TableLayoutPanel` with a single column and two rows, set the row size to 55% and 45%, and add the `DataGridView` to the second column.

**Example:**

```
var form = new Form();

var dgv = new DataGridView { Dock = DockStyle.Fill };

var table = new TableLayoutPanel 
{ 
    Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
    ColumnCount = 1,
    RowCount = 2
};

table.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.Percent, 100F));
table.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.Percent, 55F));
table.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.Percent, 45F));

table.Controls.Add(dgv, 0, 1);

form.Controls.Add(table);

form.ShowDialog();
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot @Dominic. I solve it with TableLayoutPanel and FlowLayout.